# How to check weblogic is running or not in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, weblogic

This is related to weblogic docker container. I want to deploy xxx.ear file when the servers are started. I will create extra two servers with the AdminServer, after AdminServer is created. So these are the servers which are available now.

- AdminServer
- ServerOne
- ServerTwo

I want to deploy my application using python script which will deploy application into ServerOne and ServerTwo (not to AdminServer).

I can check availability of AdminServer, using curl command. But i couldn't check the availability of other two servers using curl.

This is my bash script to run the container.

```
#!/bin/bash
AdminServer=http://localhost:7001/console/

docker run -d --name wlsadmin --hostname wlsadmin -p 7001:7001 app:0-SNAPSHOT

while [ "$status" != "SUCCESS" ]
do 
 status=`curl $AdminServer -k -s -f -o /dev/null && echo "SUCCESS" || 
 echo "ERROR"`
done

docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin --name server1 -e SERVER_NAME='server1' -e MS_PORT='8082'-p 8082:8082 app:0-SNAPSHOT createServer.sh

docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin --name server2 -e SERVER_NAME='server2' -e MS_PORT='8083'-p 8083:8083 app:0-SNAPSHOT createServer.sh

# I need to check availability of server1 and server2 here. if those servers are started then, I will run this script

 docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin  app:0-SNAPSHOT deployApplication.sh
```

I used this loop to check status of AdminServer.

```
while [ "$status" != "SUCCESS" ]
do 
 status=`curl $AdminServer -k -s -f -o /dev/null && echo "SUCCESS" || 
 echo "ERROR"`
done
```

Comment: Hello, you don't clearly explain what is the problem you're want to solve (have a look to [ask] to get create good question), please [edit] your question. thanks

Comment: @baptistemm hi, thanks for your advice. I'll edit the question. But down voting a question is not good. Because I don't have a that much reputation like you.

Comment: voting down a question and reputation are different things, and the down can be changed to up if the question is improved. I'm just trying to show which question have enough information.